# Exceptions in python. Given the definition, how to call it inside code?

Tags: python

In a library the following exception is defined:

```
exception paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException
Exception raised when authentication failed for some reason. It may be possible to retry with different credentials. (Other classes specify more specific reasons.)
```

In my code if i write:

```
except AuthenticationException:
```

I get an error.

If I write:

```
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
```

It works.

Why not:

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
```

How do I know what to write given the definition?

The library paramiko is obviously imported:

```
import paramiko
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `paramiko` package has following `__init__.py`:

```
from .ssh_exception import *
```

Then if you `import paramiko`, you will have all stuff under `paramiko` without additional subbranches